# Big O vs Big Theta

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I'm currently taking discrete math and not understanding the difference between $\Theta$(n) and O(n). The key for an assignment states that $3n^2 + 2n^{3n+2} \in \Theta(2^n)$ is false. Could someone explain why that is? I understand $\Theta$ as being a lower bound, so is $2^n$ not a lower bound for $2n^{3n}$, meaning the expression is actually true?

Additionally, another problem states that $3n^2 + 2n^{3n^2} \in O(2^{n^3})$ is true. How is $2^{n^3}$ an upper bound for $2n^{3n^2}$?

Thanks

Comment: While $2^n$ is a lower bound (in the limit) for $2n^{3n}$, it is not an upper bound (even throwing in some constant multiple).  $n^n$ grows too quickly.

Comment: $\Theta \subset O$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $\Theta(\cdot)$ is not (just) a lower bound.

$f(n)\in O(g(n))$ is an upper bound on $f(n)$: $f(n)\leq Cg(n)$ for some $C>0$ (and all sufficiently large $n$).

$f(n)\in\Omega(g(n))$ is a lower bound: $cg(n)\leq f(n)$ for some $c>0$ (and all sufficiently large $n$).

$f(n)\in\Theta(g(n))$ is **both**: $cg(n)\leq f(n)\leq Cg(n)$ for some $C>c>0$ (and all sufficiently large $n$). In other words it means $f(n)\in O(g(n))$ and $f(n)\in\Omega(g(n))$.

Here $2^n$ does not give an upper bound: $3n^2+2n^{3n}\not\in O(2^n)$, so it certainly isn't in $\Theta(2^n)$. The lower bound does hold, but that only means  $3n^2+2n^{3n}\in\Omega(2^n)$.

To answer your final question: take logs. Assuming base $2$, $\log(2n^{3n^2})=1+3n^2\log n<n^3$ for $n$ sufficiently large.